# How to Divide Array list in 3 Parts

Tags: php, arrays, list, loops, divide

```
<?php 
$count=count($admissions);
$divide=$count/3;
$divide=round($divide);

foreach($admissions as $key => $row)
{
if(//First Part ) 
{
    echo  "Alpha";} 
else if(//2nd Part )
{ 
    echo "Beta";
}else 
{
    echo "Gamma"; 
}
} 
?>
```

I have a dynamic array list and i want to divide it equally in 3 parts.

if Count of array is 30.

So i want to echo for first 10 record

echo "Alpha";

Second 10 Records

Echo "Beta";

3rd 10 Records

Echo "Gamma";

if array size is 60 then it will be divided into 20 parts each.

How can i echo the alpha, beta and gamma.

Comment: what would you do with array of count `13` ? Which will be not divisible by `3` completely.

Comment: If count is 13, then 3 parts will be contained 4,4 and rest will be 5

Comment: I hope you are expecting this.. You can check my recent post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing your question is about if conditions. So you can use this code:

```
$count=count($admissions);
$divide=$count/3;
$divide=round($divide);

$i = 1;
foreach($admissions as $key => $row)
{
    if($i > 0 && $i <= $divide) 
    {
        echo  "Alpha";
    } 
    else if($i > $divide && $i <= ($divide*2))
    { 
        echo "Beta";
    }
    else //equal else if($i > $divide*2 )
    {
        echo "Gamma"; 
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a normal for loop :

```
   For ($i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++){
      echo "alpha";
   }

   For ($i = $count; $i < 2*$count ; $i++){
      echo "beta";
   }

  For ($i = 2*$count; $i < 3*$count ; $i++){
      echo "gamma";
   }
```

Comment: i want to do it 1 loop.

Comment: its just a one list, and for first i want to echo alpha for second beta and for third part i want to echo gamma.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope you are expecting this. According to the requirement which you specified in comments.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788573)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$range=range(0,12);
$result=array_chunk($range, 4);
if(count($result[count($result)-1])!=4)
{
    $temp=$result[count($result)-1];
    unset($result[count($result)-1]);
    $result[count($result)-1]=array_merge($result[count($result)-1],$temp);
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have an `array` of three elements and play with the modulo:

```
<?php 
$count=count($admissions);
$divide=$count/3;
$divide=round($divide);
$divisions = array(0 => array(), 1 => array(), 2 => array())
$modulo = 0;

foreach($admissions as $key => $row)
{
    $divisions[($modulo + 1) % 3][$key] = $row;
}
```

This will do the partitioning you need.